Do I need resistors in my circuit?
A little backstory. This is my first time creating a PCB with SMD high power LEDs. Or rather, first time to create anything on a PCB. One of my old LED Lights used for reef aquariums was not working and was using some older tech.  So I thought, How hard could it be to recreate the same thing but with updated LEDs?
The "System":

Power Supply: 24 V, 2500 mA.
LDD driver board with 4 x LDD-1000L with PWM control to control 4 channels of LEDs.
PCB Layout. + and - pads for connecting to LDD driver board. 4 channels of LEDs. Before reaching any LED, I have placed a pad for a thermal shut off to shut the supply off if it reaches a high temp.

Channel 1 consist of 8 LEDs that will run at their peaks, 3 V and 1000 mA.
Channel 2 consist of 2 LEDs with the same current and voltage.
Channels 3 and 4 consist of 1 LED each with the same current and voltage.



Please see my picture below.

Do I need to add resistors into this PCB?  If so, what would be the best way?
I am in no way even remotely familiar with electrical.  I understand enough to get myself into trouble.
LED Datasheet.

The driver board should take care of current control but without datasheets we can't be sure of that or whether it is compatible with your LEDs.

Please [edit] your question and add a link to the datasheet for the LEDs. I'm expecting that there will be a heatsinking requirement for the LEDs that relies on good bonding to large copper pours on the PCB. You should only be etching the minimum copper between the "traces" or pours if the LEDs are high powered.

@transistor I've edited and included the datasheet for the LED majority.

Your traces are quite thin, you might consider fattening them up significantly, or even better, switching to large copper pours. This will carry heavier currents and also perform a certain amount of heat sinking

I haven't time to dig into this for you, but there's a link on page 104 of the datasheet to their paper on thermal management and this may be beneficial.

Figure 1. This picture from PCB Elec shows the idea of using copper pour to create heat dissipation and radiator zones. The white stripes are where the copper has been etched away and the beige is the copper area (all having been coated). This board has three columns of three series connected LEDs. Power would be connected to the top and bottom traces.
